# How to use Datasets with the Pytorch C++ API with simple float I/O Data?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to use the Pytorch C++ API to train a simple neural net that has float input and output values. The Values are saved in "input.csv" and a output.csv" files. There are just 10x10 inputs and outputs that represent the negation. So if the input is 1 the output is 0.

I was able to build a simple neural net by creating input and output tensors manually. The code for this is on my repo in the master branch that you can find here: [master branch repo](https://github.com/shyney7/libtorch_win_test).

But now I wanted to use `torch::data::make_data_loader` and `torch::data::datasets` to make my own custom dataset and being able to shuffle my data and also to create batch sizes for the training loop.

Unfortunately all of the examples and tutorials for the pytorch cpp API only show how to do it for complex image recognition. These examples are way to complicated for a programming beginner like me. (Just started programming a few months ago)

I've tried it myself by creating a custom dataset class as shown in most examples and then using this class to make a dataloader. You can find it here: [dataset test branch](https://github.com/shyney7/libtorch_win_test/tree/dataset_test).

I've been following a Chinese tutorial since this was the only tutorial that was somewhat beginner friendly: [Chinese Tutorial](https://www.pytorchtutorial.com/pytorch-c-api-2-custom-data-loading/).

I think what I want to accomplish is something like in this python tutorial:
[pytorch dataset loader with python](https://github.com/hunkim/PyTorchZeroToAll/blob/master/08_1_dataset_loader.py)

Here is my Class defined in src/owndata.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <vector>
//#include "include/owndata.h"

//----------------------Funktionsprototyp Onelinevector----------------------

std::vector<float>
onelinevector(const std::vector<std::vector<float>> &invector);

//------------------------Funktionsprototyp csv2Dvector----------------------

std::vector<std::vector<float>> csv2Dvector(std::string inputFileName);

//-------------------Custom Dataset Class------------------------------------

class CustomDataset : public torch::data::datasets::Dataset<CustomDataset> {

private:
std::vector<std::vector<float>> xdata, ydata;
torch::Tensor outputtensor, inputtensor;
public:
CustomDataset(std::string xpath, std::string ypath) {
    xdata = csv2Dvector(xpath);
    ydata = csv2Dvector(ypath);

    //create input tensor:
    unsigned int ivsize = xdata.size() * xdata.front().size();
    std::vector<float> olinevec(ivsize);
    olinevec = onelinevector(xdata);

    inputtensor = torch::from_blob(
      olinevec.data(), {static_cast<unsigned int>(xdata.size()),
                        static_cast<unsigned int>(xdata.front().size())});
    //create output tensor:
    unsigned int ovsize = ydata.size() * ydata.front().size();
    std::vector<float> iovec(ovsize);
    iovec = onelinevector(ydata);

    outputtensor = torch::from_blob(
      iovec.data(), {static_cast<unsigned int>(ydata.size()),
                        static_cast<unsigned int>(ydata.front().size())});
};

torch::data::Example<> get(size_t index) override {

    torch::Tensor sample_input = inputtensor[index];
    torch::Tensor sample_output = outputtensor[index];

    return {sample_input.clone(), sample_output.clone()};
};

// Return the length of data
torch::optional<size_t> size() const override {
    return ydata.size();
  };

};

size_t batch_size = 5;

//-----------------------------NETZDEFINITION-----------------------------
struct MeinNetz : torch::nn::Module {
  MeinNetz() {
    fc1 = register_module("fc1", torch::nn::Linear(10, 10));
    fc2 = register_module("fc2", torch::nn::Linear(10, 10));
  }

  torch::Tensor forward(torch::Tensor x) {
    x = torch::relu(fc1->forward(x));
    x = fc2->forward(x);
    return x;
  }

  torch::nn::Linear fc1{nullptr}, fc2{nullptr};
};


//-------------------------------------main-Funktion-------------------------

int main() {

  auto custom_dataset = CustomDataset("input.csv","output.csv");
  auto data_loader = torch::data::make_data_loader<torch::data::samplers::SequentialSampler>(std::move(custom_dataset),batch_size);

  auto dataset_size = custom_dataset.size().value();
  int n_epochs = 50;

  auto net = std::make_shared<MeinNetz>();

  torch::optim::SGD optimizer(net->parameters(), 0.2);

  for(int epoch=1; epoch<=n_epochs; epoch++) {
    for(auto& batch: *data_loader) {
      auto data = batch.data;
      auto target = batch.target;

      data = data.to(torch::kF32);
      target = target.to(torch::kF32);

      optimizer.zero_grad();

      auto prediction = net->forward(data);
      auto loss = torch::mse_loss(prediction, target);

      loss.backward();

      optimizer.step();

      std::cout << "Epoch: " << epoch << " Loss: " 
      << loss.item<float>() << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

//--------------------------Funktionen--------------------------------------------

std::vector<float>
onelinevector(const std::vector<std::vector<float>> &invector) {

  std::vector<float> v1d;
  if (invector.size() == 0)
    return v1d;
  v1d.reserve(invector.size() * invector.front().size());

  for (auto &innervector : invector) {
    v1d.insert(v1d.end(), innervector.begin(), innervector.end());
  }

  return v1d;
}

//-------------------------csv2vector Funktionsdefinition--------------------------

std::vector<std::vector<float>> csv2Dvector(std::string inputFileName) {
  using namespace std;

  vector<vector<float>> data;
  ifstream inputFile(inputFileName);
  int l = 0;

  while (inputFile) {
    l++;
    string s;
    if (!getline(inputFile, s))
      break;
    if (s[0] != '#') {
      istringstream ss(s);
      vector<float> record;

      while (ss) {
        string line;
        if (!getline(ss, line, ','))
          break;
        try {
          record.push_back(stof(line));
        } catch (const std::invalid_argument e) {
          cout << "NaN found in file " << inputFileName << " line " << l
               << endl;
          e.what();
        }
      }

      data.push_back(record);
    }
  }

  if (!inputFile.eof()) {
    cerr << "Could not read file " << inputFileName << "\n";
    throw invalid_argument("File not found.");
  }

  return data;
}
```

This is not working at all.

PS: there is also an example with Python from the pytorch repo but it's way more complicated than the Chinese example: [python example for image import 2.](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/cpp/custom-dataset/custom-dataset.cpp)

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want to accomplish? I do not understand what do you want to do

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos The thing that I am trying is to use torch::data namespace to create a DataLoader to be able to create batch sizes of my data and also to shuffle my data randomly. Because right now (master branch) Im just creating tensors manually from the data and passing everything at once per epoch. I know that this is no problem with a input and output size of just 10x10 but I also want to be able to train the model with bigger data sizes. Also shuffling the data before passing it through the model would be better.

Comment: You can add RandomSampler instead of SequentialSampler to randomize the batches

Comment: One more thing I see from your code is that you forgot to specify the public and private keywords inside the class

Comment: @HectorEstebanCabezos  thank you for your tips. I've now declared the private and public members of my class and also changed it a little. but unfortunately I'm now getting an error when specifying my targets in the training loop like this: ```auto target = batch.target;```  it says that target is no member of ```std::vector<SingleExample,std::allocator<SingleExample>``` I've committed my changes to my repo here: https://github.com/shyney7/libtorch_win_test/blob/dataset_test/wintorch.cpp everything is now in just one sourche file.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the custom object using the `.map(...)` method:

```
auto custom_dataset = CustomDataset("input.csv","output.csv");
auto data_loader = torch::data::make_data_loader<torch::data::samplers::SequentialSampler>(std::move(custom_dataset),batch_size);
```

Change to:

```
auto custom_dataset = CustomDataset("input.csv","output.csv").map(torch::data::transforms::Stack<>());
auto data_loader = torch::data::make_data_loader<torch::data::samplers::SequentialSampler>(std::move(custom_dataset),batch_size);
```

So it is not necessary to transform the tensors in the Constructor of the custom dataset.